# What's the difference between git log and git log --decorate?

Tags: git

I have test the two commands and I didn't see any difference between the output of them.

[image: git log output with and without --decorate]

The below question from front-end developer course

Using what you know about an order git log, do you see the tag in the log output? 
the correct answer is **No,** `git log --decorate` **not git log**

**What's the difference between them?**

Comment: What does the man page say about it and what's unclear there?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There seems to be a change in behavior depending on what version of `git` you're using.

Older versions of `git` (say, 1.8.x) default to *not* decorating the output of `git log`.  More recent versions of `git` (since 2.12.2) default to `--decorate=auto` (which is just like `--decorate=short` when output is to a terminal, but acts like --no-decorate otherwise).

In other words, with version 1.8.3. running `git log` I see:

```
commit 0b57f44b3371521f65eb7607310803c7e90dc023
```

But with 2.14.4 I see:

```
commit 0b57f44b3371521f65eb7607310803c7e90dc023 (HEAD -> master, origin/master)
```

I can get the same output with the older version of `git` using `git log --decorate`.

In other words, if you're running a modern version of `git`, there will be no difference in the output of `git log` and `git log --decorate`.

Answer (score 2):

With Git 2.33 (Q3 2021), the documentation is clearer regarding `git log --decorate` default value:

See [commit a0538e5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a0538e5c8baf9985a71d18a1495985441041efba) (08 Jun 2021) by [Đoàn Trần Công Danh (`sgn`)](https://github.com/sgn).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5ae1eb2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5ae1eb22c98b2e75437f8d524eaa9fc7959fa438), 08 Jul 2021)</sup>

> ### [`doc/log`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a0538e5c8baf9985a71d18a1495985441041efba): correct default for --decorate
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Andy AO</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Đoàn Trần Công Danh</sup>

> There're two different default options for log --decorate: * Should `--decorate` be given without any arguments, it's default to `short` * Should neither `--decorate` nor `--no-decorate` be given, it's default to the `log.decorate` or `auto`.
>
> We documented the former, but not the latter.
>
> Let's document them, too.

`git log` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a0538e5c8baf9985a71d18a1495985441041efba/Documentation/git-log.txt#L42-L44):

> The option `--decorate` is short-hand for `--decorate=short`.
>
> Default to configuration value of `log.decorate` if configured,
> otherwise, `auto`.